# How to sort by the smallest value from multiple fields?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have list of mongo documents

```
[
  {
    "created_at": "2024-03-15T18:11:18.687",
    "updated_at": "2024-03-15T18:11:28.945",
    "fields": {
      "contract_first": [],
      "contract_second": [
        {
          "position": "Bob"
        }
      ],
      "uuid": "bf031b46-ec33-4c61-ad33-a3ad2cbeb9cb"
    },
    "id": "65f46520928f6fd496ffbe6d"
  },
  {
    "created_at": "2024-03-15T18:11:18.687",
    "updated_at": "2024-03-15T18:15:26.838",
    "fields": {
      "contract_first": [
        {
          "position": "Anna"
        }
      ],
      "contract_second": [],
      "uuid": "bf052b46-ec33-4c61-ad33-a3ad2cbeb9cb"
    },
    "id": "65f4660e928f6fd496ffbeb0"
  },
  {
    "created_at": "2024-03-15T18:11:18.687",
    "updated_at": "2024-03-15T18:15:26.838",
    "fields": {
      "contract_first": [
        {
          "position": "Bob"
        }
      ],
      "contract_second": [],
      "uuid": "bf092b46-ec33-4c61-ad33-a3ad2cbeb9cb"
    },
    "id": "65f8660e928f6fd496ffbeb0"
  }
]
```

Which has 2 main array fields `contract_first` and `contract_second` and i want to know how to sort my document by 2 that array fields?

I was trying to use

```
{
  '$sort': {
    'fields.contract_first.position': 1,
    'fields.contract_second.position': 1
  }
}
```

But I have got an error `cannot sort with keys that are parallel arrays`

For example Output should be like:
Anna
Bob
Bob
even if they are in different fields

Comment: what do you want to do if there is more than one item in the array?

Comment: Nothing, there is cant be more than 1 item in this array but unfortunately its architecture so i cant make dict in this field. It will be everytime array

Comment: And what do you want to do with `{ contract_first: [{ position: "Ellen" }], contract_second: []` and `{ contract_first: [], contract_second: [{ position: "Dave" }]`? Should **E**llen come before **D**ave? Does the data always imply that only one contract array will have data?

Comment: No, it should go in alphabetic ordering, so Dave then Ellen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since mongoDB version 5.2, one option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {sort_key: {$sortArray: {
          input: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$fields.contract_first.position",
              "$fields.contract_second.position"
            ]
          },
          sortBy: 1
  }}}},
  {$sort: {sort_key: 1}},
  {$unset: "sort_key"}
])
```

See How it works on the [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NOfsFpRlZKP)

Comment: Nice, the `sortBy` handles the issue present in my solution  +1

Comment: Also, using example data with only relevant fields / easier to see the results: [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bmUF7ObOREV)

Comment: Edit: oops, it looks like we both spoke too soon: [even this solution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vbt-WOVxtNK) will sort  `{ first: Ellen, second: Charlie }` before `{ first: Dave, second: Charlie }`

Answer (score 1):

Wrt wanting "Dave" before "Ellen" even in the case of *`{ contract_first: [{ position: "Ellen" }], contract_second: [] }` vs `{ contract_first: [], contract_second: [{ position: "Dave" }] }`*

If only *first or second* contract will have an entry but not both, then you can do this:
Assign a sort_key based on the first non-null value of each, and then sort on that value.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      sort_key: {
        $ifNull: [
          { $first: "$fields.contract_first.position" },
          { $first: "$fields.contract_second.position" }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { sort_key: 1 } }
])
```

However, in cases where both first & second contract can exist, you'll need to re-add the 2nd contract as a sort_key.

So here, I've created two of them: `sort_key1` is the first non-null contract with a position between `first_contract` & `second_contract` and `sort_key2` is only the `second_contract`. So `sort_key2` would get used when `sort_key1` is the same.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      sort_key1: {
        $ifNull: [
          { $first: "$fields.contract_first.position" },
          { $first: "$fields.contract_second.position" }
        ]
      },
      sort_key2: { $first: "$fields.contract_second.position" }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      sort_key1: 1,
      sort_key2: 1
    }
  },
  {
    // comment this out to see the sort_keys
    $unset: ["sort_key1", "sort_key2"]
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground with better data](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8yVCaPm6YhG) examples.

Comment: This solution will won't handle a case like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4gZ3YjjZGh-): `"fields": {"contract_first": [ {"position": "Ellen" }], "contract_second": [ { "position": "Anna" }] }`

Comment: This would still give strange results for cases like `first: null, second: Dave`, `first: Dave, second: Charlie`, `first: Ellen, second: Charlie`. It's unclear if you want to consider the names in both to also be sorted.

Comment: @nimrodserok I assume you mean _won't handle_ a case like ... :-) Yes, I need to sort the names in both before considering the key. Will update & edit

Comment: I updated the comment to include the missing `won't`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For use cases involving custom sorting logic, one of the common solution patterns is creating a custom sort key and sorting on it. This provides flexibility as you can simply update the logic of the sort key if the situation changes.

For your case, I create a `sortKey` with below logic:

1. `firstKey`: pick `contract_first.position`, if it is null, `$ifNull` to fall back to MaxKey(the maximum type in sorting in MongoDB, see [this doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#examples), or you can use any value that you are sure that it will be larger than possible values in the field)
2. `secondKey`: pick `contract_second.position`, if it is null, `$ifNull` to fall back to MaxKey
3. create composite Key sortKey: {key1, key2}, which `key1` is smaller of `firstKey` and `secondKey`, and `key2` is larger of them

After the creation of the sort key, just sort the result on `sortKey`. Feel free to remove the sort key after usage. You can potentially materialize/persist the key if you don't want to compute it often.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      firstKey: {
        "$ifNull": [
          {
            "$first": "$fields.contract_first.position"
          },
          {
            "$maxKey": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      secondKey: {
        "$ifNull": [
          {
            "$first": "$fields.contract_second.position"
          },
          {
            "$maxKey": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "sortKey": {
        "key1": {
          "$min": [
            "$firstKey",
            "$secondKey"
          ]
        },
        "key2": {
          "$max": [
            "$firstKey",
            "$secondKey"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "sortKey": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "firstKey",
      "secondKey",
      "sortKey"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vxBN-_ghr7F)

Comment: Good explanation about the needed concept. But this solution has the same problem is mine: `{ first: Ellen, second: Charlie }` [would sort before](https://mongoplayground.net/p/95n-3zvi-ZM) `{ first: Dave, second: Charlie }` - OP wants to use the names from first & second to also be part of the sort key.

Comment: @aneroid Thanks for pointing that out. This is a valid and helpful concern. I have updated the `sortKey` logic according to your test cases. What I want to highlight is the adaptability of the fact that the sort key serves as an abstraction / interface for sorting logic and OP can feel free to improvise and change it with minimal friction in future. Other than that, I would say nimrod serok's and your answer would be a far cleaner and more concise solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

*After creating much better test data with edge-cases, etc.*

Currently, [only Ray's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78181732/1431750) provides the correct order wrt `{ first: Ellen, second: Charlie }` before `{ first: Dave, second: Charlie }`.

OP also needs to decide what to about the ordering for `{ first: Dave, second: [] }` vs `{ first: [], second: Dave }` vs `{ first: Dave, second: Dave }`. This will require using [`minKey` or `maxKey`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#minkey-and-maxkey) like in Ray's answer or treating them the same and using a third field like `_id` or `created_at` in case of ties, which is what I've done below.

Here's a slightly modified version which combines elements of the [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78181732/1431750) [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78181171/1431750) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78181068/1431750):

- Considers names from both arrays and uses alphabetical order

  - so `{ first: Ellen, second: Charlie }` before `{ first: Dave, second: Charlie }`
- Then uses record-order when both names match

  - so `{ first: Dave, second: Ellen }` before `{ first: Ellen, second: Dave }`
- Then uses the `_id` for 4-way ties

  - change this as needed, to another field like `created_at` or `updated_at`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      // add both the position-names to an array
      // but don't sort here
      names: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$fields.contract_first.position",
          "$fields.contract_second.position"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // convert to lowercase, skip if not needed
    // can be combined with the set above
    $set: {
      names: {
        $map: {
          input: "$names",
          as: "name",
          in: { $toLower: "$$name" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // use each name as the sort key
    // using alphabetical order and then record order
    $set: {
      sort_key1: { $min: "$names" },
      sort_key2: { $max: "$names" },
      sort_key3: { $first: "$names" },
      sort_key4: { $last: "$names" }
    }
  },
  {
    // use each of the keys to sort & _id if necessary
    $sort: {
      sort_key1: 1,
      sort_key2: 1,
      sort_key3: 1,
      sort_key4: 1,
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    // comment this out to see the sort_keys
    $unset: ["names", "sort_key1", "sort_key2", "sort_key3", "sort_key4"]
  }
])
```

[Mongo playground with streamlined data and edge-cases](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tqHi6pK9pbD)